# Updating the content dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get the idea how this one would work. Basically, I will create two dropdown lists.

```
<select id="dropdown1">
 <option value="v1">value1</option>
 <option value="v2">value2</option>
 <option value="v3">value3</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdown2">
 <option value="apple">apple</option>
 <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>

<label id="value1">Value 1:</label>
<div id="showDropDown2"></div>

<label id="value2">Value 2:</label>
<div id="showDropDown2"></div>

<label id="value3">Value 3:</label>
<div id="showDropDown2"></div>
```

For example, when user selects "value2" from dropdown 1 and select "orange" from dropdown 2. Then it wll update the div content at Value 2 section. When user selects "value3", and select "apple" from dropdown 2. Then it will update the div content at Value 3 section. And so on.

Comment: He didn't ask you for code he asked for a starting point. It's as if he said "I would like to get the idea how this one would work" not, hey write some code snap snap.

Comment: If you noticed he's asking about things that would be made a lot easier by the library JQuery but he didn't mention it in his post. It's clear op is just really new to the language and doesn't know where to get a starting point.

Comment: I'm trying to use JavaScript only. What I don't know how to do is when user selects the option from dropdown 1, how can I update the div content from whatever the option user has selected.  I'm not asking to write me the code, but at least gives me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) would be a helpful library to use. Look into jquery's show and hide functions. Example

```
$('#value1').hide()
```

after you've hidden the stuff needed to be hidden, hook events to the checklists using the .on  function. These functions can be found on the Jquery website.